# Xamarin ios compile to Iphone fails after updating to the latest Xcode and VS

Tags: c#, xcode, xamarin, xamarin.ios, linker-errors

I have a project which is use `XCardView` for a while.(I've already distributed the app to the app store.)
I updated both VS and XCode to the latest version.

Now when I execute my project in emulator everything works fine.
However when I tried to compile it to device, the operation fails with 3 errors:

[image]

1:

> Error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

2:

> Error MT5211: Native linking failed, undefined Objective-C class: ZLSwipeableViewDelegate. The symbol '_OBJC_CLASS_$_ZLSwipeableViewDelegate' could not be found in any of the libraries or frameworks linked with your application. (MT5211)

3:

> Error MT5202: Native linking failed. Please review the build log. (MT5202)

I've read [MT5211 link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/troubleshooting/mtouch-errors#MT5211) for the errors but I have no clue with how to solve it since I don't have the source code of `XCardView` library and in the log I don't find any interesting information...

BTW, I didn't change my project settings at all.

Is there any idea on a way to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance :)

Edit 1:

I didn't change any project settings except adding new classes files.
Here is my project conf:

[image]

Edit 2:

XCardView was a Xamarin Component. Since the component store is no longer available the entire component can be found [here](https://github.com/MikeCodesDotNet/Bait-News/tree/master/Components/XCardView-1.1)

Comment: I can't find plugin called `XCardView ` ,can you provide the project url of `XCardView `?

Comment: @ColeXia-MSFT it is not a plugin. It was a Xamarin Component. [Here you can find the this Xamarin Component](https://github.com/MikeCodesDotNet/Bait-News/tree/master/Components/XCardView-1.1). Thank you very much for the support!

Comment: I'm afraid you have to contact the author or report the issue , and by the way I recommend you to use [ZLSwipeableView](https://github.com/zhxnlai/ZLSwipeableView)

Comment: @ColeXia-MSFT `XCardView` bind ZLSwipeableView behind the skin. Once I realised that this is not a simple bug I tried to contact the [author](https://www.softwebsolutions.com/) bug I got 404... Then I decompile the dll using [DotPeek](https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) to see how can I create a new binding project. But I have failed with it. Then I asked this question...

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on the ios solution, you will see iOS build option there you can set the linker property to Link From SDK only.

Comment: Thank you for the support however my project settings is already configure like this...